# add headers to a response fired by ChannelHandlerContext (Netty)

Tags: java, scala, netty, middleware, channel

I have a jar, that I can't edit, that adds several headers to an http response. It then takes the response and`ctx.writeAndFlush(resp)`

Is there a way to catch this response elsewhere (like a middleware) and edit it (add/remove headers, etc)?

The code uses Netty http tranport

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `ChannelHandlerContext` (ctx), the `Channel` or the `Pipeline`  through which the response propagates. Then you can access the response by adding a `ChannelOutboundHandler` to the `Pipeline` and overriding the `write` or the `flush` method of this handler. In these methods you can modify the response.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can add your own `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` and override `write(...)`. Here you can adjust the `response` on the fly before you call `ctx.write(...)` again and pass it on.

Just ensure you put your handler before the other handler in the `ChannelPipeline`.